# Why is jQuery autocomplete updating all elements on my cloned form?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form that uses the jQuery UI autocomplete function on two elements, and also has the ability to clone itself using the [SheepIt!](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB) plugin.

Both elements are text inputs.  Once a a value is selected from the first autocomplete (continents), the values of the second autocomplete (countries) are populated with options dependent on the first selection.

My problem is, when clones are made, if the user selects an option from the first autocomplete (continent), it changes the first input values on all clones.  This is not happening for the second input (country).

What am I missing?

Note: the #index# in the form id and name is not CFML.  I am using PHP, and the hash tags are part of the SheepIt! clone plugin.

Javascript:

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.sheepIt.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    function ord(chr) {

        return chr.charCodeAt(0);

    }

    function chr(num) {

        return String.fromCharCode(num);

    }

    function quote(str) {

        return '"' + escape(str.replace('"', "'")) + '"';

    }

    String.prototype.titleCase = function () {

        var chars = [" ", "-"];
        var ths = String(this).toLowerCase();

        for (j in chars){

            var car = chars[j];
            var str = "";
            var words = ths.split(car);
            for(i in words){

                str += car + words[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);

            }

            ths = str.substr(1);

        }

        return ths;

    }

    function incrementTerm(term) {

        for (var i = term.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){

            var code = term.charCodeAt(i);

            if (code < ord('Z'))

                return term.substring(0, i) + chr(code + 1);

        }

        return '{}'

    }

    function parseLineSeperated(data){

        data = data.split("\n");

        data.pop(); // Trim blank element after ending newline

        var out = []

        for (i in data){

            out.push(data[i].titleCase());

        }

        return out;

    }

    function loadcontinent(request, response) {

        var startTerm = request.term.toUpperCase();

        var endTerm = incrementTerm(startTerm);

        $.ajax({

            url: '/db/continent.php?startkey='+startTerm+'&endkey='+endTerm,

            success: function(data) {

                var items = parseLineSeperated(data);

                response(items);

            },

            error: function(req, str, exc) {

                alert(str);

            }

            });

    }

    function loadcountry(request, response) {

        var startTerm = request.term.toUpperCase();

        var endTerm = incrementTerm(startTerm);

        var continent = $('.continent_autocomplete').val().toUpperCase();

        $.ajax({

            url: '/db/country.php?key=' + continent,

            success: function(data) {

                var items = parseLineSeperated(data);

                response(items);


            },

            error: function(req, str, exc) {

                alert(str);

            }

            });

    }

    $('#location_container_add').live('click', function() { 
        $("input.continent_autocomplete").autocomplete(continent_autocomplete);
        $("input.continent_autocomplete").keyup(continent_autocomplete_keyup);  
        $("input.country_autocomplete").autocomplete(country_autocomplete);     
        $("input.country_autocomplete").keyup(country_autocomplete_keyup);      
        $('input.country_autocomplete').focus(country_autocomplete_focus);
    });


    var location_container = $('#location_container').sheepIt({
            separator: '',
            allowRemoveLast: true,
            allowRemoveCurrent: false,
            allowRemoveAll: false,
            allowAdd: true,
            allowAddN: false,
            maxFormsCount: 10,
            minFormsCount: 1,
            iniFormsCount: 1
    });

    var continent_autocomplete = {

        source: loadcontinent,

        select: function(event, ui){

            $("input.continent_autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);

        }

    }

    var continent_autocomplete_keyup = function (event){

        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        event.target.value = event.target.value.titleCase();

    }

    var country_autocomplete = {

        source: loadcountry,

    }

    var country_autocomplete_keyup = function (event){

        event.target.value = event.target.value.titleCase();

    }

    var country_autocomplete_focus = function(){           
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", " ");
        }
    }   

    $("input.continent_autocomplete").autocomplete(continent_autocomplete);
    $("input.continent_autocomplete").keyup(continent_autocomplete_keyup);
    $("input.country_autocomplete").autocomplete(country_autocomplete);
    $("input.country_autocomplete").keyup(country_autocomplete_keyup);
    $('input.country_autocomplete').focus(country_autocomplete_focus);

});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="location_container">
    <div id="location_container_template" class="location_container">
        <div id="continent_name">
            <label> Continent Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="continent_name_#index#" name="continent_name_#index#" class="continent_autocomplete" />
        </div>
        <div id="country">
            <label> Country:</label>
            <input type="text" id="country_autocomplete_#index#" name="country_autocomplete_#index#" class="country_autocomplete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select: function(event, ui){

        $("input.continent_autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);

    }
```

That code says explicitly to set the value of every `<input>` with class "continent_autocomplete" to the selected value.

You probably want something like

```
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
```

but it depends on how your autocomplete code works.

Comment: ahhh, thanks so much.  think i've been starting at this too long! :)

Answer (score 1):

This line: `$("input.continent_autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);` is updating all inputs with class `continent_autocomplete`.

**UPDATE:**
From [jQueryUI Autocomplete Doc:select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu; ui.item refers to
>   the selected item. The default action of select is to replace the text
>   field's value with the value of the selected item. Canceling this
>   event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the
>   menu from closing.

You shouldn't need the `select` bit at all, it looks like you're simply trying to achieve the default action.

Comment: This offers no answer? just highlights the problem.. probably should have been a comment or edit the OP...

Comment: I was getting there, sorry for the delay. The question was "What am I missing?" which I technically answered.